# Setting zeros (0)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are trying to add "0" to empty cells in a Google Spreadsheets. 
What we have come up with so far is the following code, but it set's 0 to **all** cells in the sheet. We would like it to only set on cell **B:Q**.

[image]

We tried to change the following, but with the same results:

```
   range = source.getRange("B1:Q1", lastRow, lastColumn);
```

And the complete code-snipet we use looks like this:

```
function zeroDatarange() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  zero(range, null);
}


function zero(source, type) {
  var data, range;
  if(type === 'sheet') {
    var lastRow = source.getMaxRows();
    var lastColumn = source.getMaxColumns();    
    range = source.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  } else {
    range = source;
  }
  data = range.getValues();
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    for(var j = 0, jLen = data[0].length; j < jLen; j++) {
      if(!data[i][j]) {
        data[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }  
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `zero()` with the arguments of the whole data range which includes column A.
Then you check if `type == 'sheet'`.
You are passing `null` though so the `range` you are pasting to is set to `source` (the complete data range including column A).

Not sure what other uses you will have for `zero()` function but you'll need to set `range` in `zero()` to `range = source.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);`.
You can do this either in the `else` clause or by changing the passed argument from `null` to `'sheet'` and editing the range assignment to start from the second column.

Comment: Hi Robin, We try to set null to 'Sheet' and try to set source.getRange(2, 5, lastRow, lastColumn) for example, but it still puts 0 in the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This worked pretty good, editing B2:Q200. Thanks Robin Gertenbach for the help.

```
 function zeroSheet() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      zero(sheet, 'sheet');
    }

    function zero(source, type) {
      var data, range;
      if(type === 'sheet') {
        var lastRow = source.getMaxRows();
        var lastColumn = source.getMaxColumns();   
       Logger.log(lastColumn);
        range = source.getRange(2, 2, 200, 16);
      } else {
        range = source;
      }
      data = range.getValues();
      for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
        for(var j = 0, jLen = data[0].length; j < jLen; j++) {
          if(!data[i][j]) {
            data[i][j] = 0;
          }
        }
      }  
      range.setValues(data);
    }
```